# Find column name SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, identity-column

If it is possible, I want to return another column that contains the name of the column where the variable is found `(CH1, CH2 or CH3)`.

Something like:

```
v1 => ch3

v2 => ch1
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT variable
FROM Variables , Names
WHERE (Variables.ID = Names.Ch1 or  Variables.ID = Names.Ch2 or Variables.ID = Names.Ch3 )
```

The format of my tables:

```
Names(#ID,Ch2,Ch2,Ch3)
Variables(#ID, variable,...)
```

I tried with `%columName%` but I get an error.

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is more like:

```
select v.*,
       (case when v.id = n.ch1 then 'CH1'
             when v.id = n.ch2 then 'CH2'
             when v.id = n.ch3 then 'CH3'
        end) as WhichColumn
from variables v join
     names n
     on v.ID  in (n.Ch1, n.ch2, n.ch3)
```

In other words, you have to explicitly put in the logic for the column names.

Comment: That's what I want ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using the LIKE if the variables ID are **NOT** only INT number

```
SELECT variable
FROM Variables , Names
WHERE 
(Variables.ID like '%Names.Ch1%' 
or  Variables.ID  like '%Names.Ch2%' 
or Variables.ID like '%Names.Ch3%' )
```